# How to have one instance of QNetworkAccessManager?

Tags: c++, qt, oop, c++11, design-patterns

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46056808/qnetworkaccessmanager-one-instance-and-connecting-slots) but I did not find it useful for my problem.

In Qt [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details), they say:

> One QNetworkAccessManager instance should be enough for the whole Qt application.

In my application, I was using `QNetworkAccessManager` in several places (they may be called simultaneously) and each time I was creating new instance on the stack. After reading that quote I changed my code to have one static `QNetworkAccessManager` and using it everywhere. After changing it to static member, I always get a warning:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::aboutToQuit() to QNativeWifiEngine::closeHandle()
```

In both cases, the code is working without errors, however, that documentation is confusing me a little bit. As the product is going to be commercial, I am taking this issue serious. Should I follow a documentation or avoid a warning? Or do you suggest any other ways?

What if an object on a different thread needs to use a `QNetworkAccessManager`?

---

EDIT: adding code

Singleton settings class:

```
class ConnectionSettingsSingleton
{
   ...
   // constructors = default
   // copy constructor = delete

   public:
      static QNetworkAccessManager networkAccessManager;
}
```

I use `networkAccessManager` in different places, but the same way:

```
QNetworkReply* HttpClient::makeRequest()
{
   switch (this->method) {
   case RequestMethod::GET:
      return ConnectionSettingsSingleton::networkAccessManager.get(this->serverRequest);
   case RequestMethod::POST:
      return ConnectionSettingsSingleton::networkAccessManager.post(this->serverRequest, QJsonDocument(this->data).toJson());
   case RequestMethod::DELETE:
      return ConnectionSettingsSingleton::networkAccessManager.deleteResource(this->serverRequest);
   default:
      return nullptr;
   }
}
```

---

EDIT-2

I was kindly using [Kuba Ober's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50691392/6407320) and at one point I got this warning:

```
QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QNetworkAccessManager(0x26f6d0), parent's thread is QThread(0x2b73b8), current thread is QThread(0xa4f20a8)
```

Reason: I tried to access `QNAM` from a different thread. Accordingly, I updated my question.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have entire Qt at your disposal. Do not use static variables for this - you don't control their lifetime, and that lifetime is almost always wrong. The `QNetworkManager` should not exist when `QCoreApplication` doesn't exist. The warning is not benign at all - it indicates a fundamental design issue. **You** need to control the lifetime of the manager, and ensure that it doesn't outlive `QApplication`. The canonical way to manage such global application-tied objects is to keep them as automatic variables in `main` and use helper functions to access them. The `QPointer` automatically tracks the lifetime of the object, and thus won't ever be dangling. Thus:

#### main.h - interface

```
QNetworkAccessManager *nMgr();
```

#### main.cpp - implementation

```
// This pointer is local to the translation unit, and is an
// implementation detail. It's not used anywhere else.
static QPointer<QNetworkAccessManager> globalManager;

// The global accessor method
QNetworkAccessManager *nMgr() {
  Q_ASSERT(!qApp || QThread::currentThread() == qApp->thread());
  return globalManager;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
  globalManager = &mgr;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I updated my question. Could you please elaborate more on your answer!?

Comment: @Bobur No, you've added an unrelated question to an already answered one. The question you now have is something else and needs to be answered elsewhere. Anyway, you cannot access QNAM from any thread other than the one where you created it, **because its methods are not documented to be thread safe**. QNAM is not special in any way: if a `QObject` method is not documented thread safe - it's not. QNAM is like a handle to a network access manager system managed by Qt. If you need to use it in other threads, create the instances there.

Comment: thank you for your kind answer! That was the only thing that came to my mind.